# HSQLDB with Postgresql: type not found or user lacks privilege: BIGSERIAL

Tags: java, unit-testing, hsqldb

I'm building Spring+Hibernate Java Application. I wanted to add some integration tests, done in *in-memory* database.

So, my normal database is Postgresql, and I populate it using .sql scripts run with flyway plugin. ID fields are set to BIGSERIAL. I wanted to use *in-memory* database, to resemble my original database, and then try to test some classes with it. I managed to configure preety much everything(I hope so), but when I run the test class itself I get error with CREATE TABLE scripts:

*Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: type not found or user lacks privilege: BIGSERIAL*

I found out that I should configure HSQLDB, to enable Postgresql compability. 
*Use SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX PGS TRUE or the equivalent URL property sql.syntax_pgs=true to enable the PostgreSQL's non-standard features.*

I use persistence.xml to define normal and test persistence unit. This is fragment responsible for defining test persistence unit:

```
<persistence-unit name="testJPA">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:butterfly;sql.syntax_pgs=true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Then I use configuration class for tests:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"core.utilities"} )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestsInitializer {
    @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("testJPA");
        return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

And in testclass itself:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestsInitializer.class }/*, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class*/)
@Transactional
public class GenreBATest {  
    @Autowired
    private GenreBA genreBA;

    @Test
    public void testFindAllAccounts() {
        //whatever
    }

}
```

I added the required property at the end of URL, found examples of this exact property across the internet, but it does not resolve my problem.

I'm still getting: *Message    : type not found or user lacks privilege: BIGSERIAL*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out that scripts were run by flyway ignoring all possible syntax commands from persistence.xml. And flyway run with HSQLDB because I used @EnableAutoConfiguration in test configuration class without excludes :) I learned through hard way that Spring Boot already configures Hibernate to create schema based on entities for an *in-memory* database. So I don't need to use database scripts at all, and they were run by accident.